# Error: <target>.ColumnName and <source>.ColumnName have conflicting properties: DataType property mismatch

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, datatable

I am trying to merge multiple excel files using DataTable.Merge() option

```
    For Each fileName As String In Directory.GetFiles("C:\TEMP\.", "*.xls")
        Dim connectionString As String = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;""", fileName)
        Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connectionString)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        adapter.Fill(ds, "anyNameHere")
        Dim TempTable As DataTable
        TempTable = ds.Tables.Item("anyNameHere")
        table1.Merge(TempTable)
        MsgBox(fileName)
    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table1
    MsgBox(table1.Rows.Count)
```

But gives following error while merging

```
<target>.ColumnName and <source>.ColumnName have conflicting properties: DataType property mismatch.
```

This is due to one column in excel is read as text and another as double while both have numeric values.

To avoid this I also mentioned IMEX=1 in connection string, still getting this error.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use MissingSchemaAction.Ignore as MissingSchemaAction parameter in Merge

```
table1.Merge(TempTable, True, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
```

Comment: Note: The question and answer is of VB.Net, hence the True used is for capitalized

Answer (score 2):

If the columns are numeric, correct the xls file treating that column as text.
Wouldn't you want the columns to be structurally same, when you merge the data?

Comment: Both are of type text. but this when the files are read using ADO it decides the column by looking at the fileds data.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007

For which I hv added IMEX=1 but still it is not working