# Checking value in column foreach row

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, rows

The DataTable (dt) stores the retrieved values of carID's and makes so it stores like 3 rows within the DataTable, I also have another DataTable called dt2 which also stores carID's and makes, I am trying to loop through each row in the dt to see if any carID stored in the dt exists in any of the rows in dt2, here is what I have so far:

```
DataTable dt = w.getUserCars(userID);

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
  string carID = dr["carID"].ToString();

}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using `DataTable.Select()` method.  You are on the right track.  You just need to add the method to find the `Row`(s) in `dt2`.

```
DataTable dt = w.getUserCars(userID);
DataRow[] foundRows;

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
  string carID = dr["carID"].ToString();

  foundRows = dt2.Select("carID = " + carID);
  // do stuff here with foundRows

  foreach (DataRow r in foundRows)
  {
    r.Delete();
  }
}
```

Comment: Would it not be possible to do an IF statement to check if any of the carID's in d1 exist in dt2?

Comment: `if (foundRows.Count > 0)` would give you the result you need.  Or you could use LINQ like some of the other answers suggest.

Comment: Well I need to specifically get a row so I can remove it

Comment: I will add an edit to my answer to show you how to accomplish this.

Comment: "DataTable does not contain a definition for remove"

Comment: Also note, this will only mark the row for deletion.  You will need to call the `Update` method on your `DataAdapter` to perform the deletion.

Comment: Oops, it's `.Delete()`, will fix the answer.

Comment: It also doesnt contain a definition for delete also

Comment: Ah, `Delete()` actually has to be called on the row, updated answer again.

Comment: Thanks, what if I wanted to add the rows that weren't the same to the dt1?

Comment: I would post a new question for that.  Are you meaning, anything in `dt2` that is not in `dt1` should be added to `dt1`?

Comment: You should be able to use the `Merge()` method, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx).

Comment: So just using a simple Merge() would solve the problem?

Comment: Perhaps, give it a try and see if it does what you are looking for.

Comment: It says both carID's from both tables have conflicting properties

Comment: If you are having issues with the `Merge()` method, try to post another question with what exactly you are trying to do.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/535767/3101082) answer may be helpful.