# C# Map .net DataTable to TemplateEngine Docx Word Table

Tags: c#

I am using [TemplateEngine.Docx](https://github.com/UNIT6-open/TemplateEngine.Docx), Template engine for generating Word docx

I am trying to MAP DataTable Result to Word Document Table, Below Code snippet is doing this by hard coding

```
var valuesToFill = new Content(
   // Add table.
   new TableContent("Team Members Table")
   .AddRow(
     new FieldContent("Name", "Eric"),
     new FieldContent("Role", "Program Manager"))
   .AddRow(
     new FieldContent("Name", "Bob"),
     new FieldContent("Role", "Developer")),
   // Add field inside table that not to propagate.
     new FieldContent("Count", "2")
);
```

I have Tried below code but I am not able to figure it out,

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Clear();
        dt.Columns.Add("SOE_DT");
        dt.Columns.Add("SOE_TM");
        dt.Columns.Add("SOE_EV"); 

        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "19/07/2017", "16:00", "This is First Event" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "19/07/2017", "16:30", "This is Second Event" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "19/07/2017", "17:00", "This is Third Event" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "19/07/2017", "18:00", "This is Fourth Event" });

TableContent tblSEQOfEvents = new TableContent("SEQOfEvents");
foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
        {
  //I Need to Add here tblSEQOfEvents.AddRow
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                tblSEQOfEvents.AddRow(
                    new FieldContent(dc.ColumnName, dtRow[dc].ToString()
                    ));
            }
        }
```

The Result is showing in Image. I know that because of for each column loop it loops 12 times instead of 4 times I just show the snipped if some one help me to correct it.
Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

by [This Stackoverflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950415/checking-value-in-column-foreach-row) I am able to get it done by following code, is it right way or it can me improve ?

```
foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
        {
            string SOE_DT = dtRow["SOE_DT"].ToString();
            string SOE_TM = dtRow["SOE_TM"].ToString();
            string SOE_EV = dtRow["SOE_EV"].ToString();

            tblSEQOfEvents.AddRow(
                    new FieldContent("SOE_DT", SOE_DT),
                    new FieldContent("SOE_TM", SOE_TM),
                    new FieldContent("SOE_EV", SOE_EV)
                    );

        }
```

[image]

Comment: What is the question you are asking? What are you trying to accomplish? I see "I am trying to MAP DataTable Result to Word Document Table" but this doesn't actually tell us what result you are looking for. Try to include an example of the result you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks for comments, The first code snippet shows how to set a values of Table in Word Document using the Template I mentioned the URL which I am using i.e. https://github.com/UNIT6-open/TemplateEngine.Docx I want that manually code to be done by using c# .Net DataTable, I showed the code I used and also the picture of the Result Desired result only show the four rows as the sample datatable is having four Rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TableContent.AddRow accepts IContentItem[]..

may be something like this..

```
        foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
        {
            //I Need to Add here tblSEQOfEvents.AddRow
            List<IContentItem> items = new List<IContentItem>();
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                items.Add(new FieldContent(dc.ColumnName, dtRow[dc].ToString()));
            }
            tblSEQOfEvents.AddRow(items.ToArray());
        }
```

Comment: Perfect, Works like a charm Thanks you very much