# Ignore conflicting properties: DataType property mismatch using DataTable.Merge()

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

Is there a way to ignore `DataType property` while merging different tables?

**Reason**: From the below `method()`, all `dtArray` come from other methods (converting different `Excel` data to `DataTable`). After cleansing enough `Excel` data, it looks that some `Datacolumn` in `dtArray` still have formatting issues yielding to (as an illustration):

`*<target>. % Value and <source> % Value have conflicting properties: Datatype property mismatch*`

I've realized it after debugging it.

for `i=0`, all works naturally since `dtAll`  has been initialized.

```
public DataTable MergeAllDataTable(DataTable[] dtArray)
{
    DataTable dtAll = new DataTable();

    for (int i = 0; i < dtArray.Length; i++)
    {
        DataTable dtget = dtArray[i];
        dtAll.Merge(dtget, true);                   
     }
     return dtAll;
}
```

**Aim:** Instead of going `Column` per `Column` and fix any formatting issues, I was wondering if `options` such as ignore `DataType property` exist since I've not been aware of it so far.

**Update**: Finally the option I was looking for is `Merge(tbl, true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)`. What has still caused a confusion is the inclusion of this `option` within above `MergeAllDataTable()`.
As a matter of fact I've used `dtAll.Merge(dtget, true,MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);` within the related scope which has still triggered the error.

Thus as a way around, acknowledging it's not really efficient, I am declaring
`Table1.Merge(Table2,true,MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)`,`Table3.Merge(Table4,true,MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)`, etc., to sort the `property mismatch`. However it could be interesting to see a better way of handling it via `loops` as initially attempted in `MergeAllDataTable()`

Best

Comment: So what happens with your current code? It would be easier to help if you'd expand this into a [mcve].

Comment: thanks for your feedback, however i was just wondering if someone has been aware of options such as `Ignore Datatype property` while merging datatables.

Comment: In order for there to be "options" there has to be a specific problem. You've now improved the question somewhat, but a [mcve] would make it *much* better. The better your question is, the more likely you are to get helpful answers... and the more useful your question will be for future readers. Please put the effort in to make this a good question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: <target>.ColumnName and <source>.ColumnName have conflicting properties: DataType property mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535749/error-target-columnname-and-source-columnname-have-conflicting-properties)